# web.confg is appending the phyiscal folder name to the end of the redirected url

Tags: asp.net, redirect

Network solutions (NetSol from now on) has an open source package available called BlogEngine.NET and the version they offer is 2.5.  you can see it working on my server with this address:  www.daleallen.net/blog25   You will note that it comes up just fine.  The physical folder it is installed on is www\blog25 in NetSol's control panel.

But when configure the NetSol pointers to point to the same physical folder using a new URL which is http://blog25.daleallen.net the page looks all screwed up.  Then when I check the properties of a hyperlink, it shows me http://blog25.daleallen.net/BLOG25  which means it added the physical folder name to the end of the URL, screwing up the page and the path to the images folder.

NetSol creates a web.config file for the redirection and installs it on the root of my shared hosting package. I am told that they are using IIS 7 on a Windows 2008 Server.

Can anyone tell me what they are doing wrong that is adding the name of the physical folder to the end of the redirected URL?  See the contents of the web.config file below...

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule platformId="wdpVpr" name="blog25.daleallen.net virtual path rewrite"      stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^.*$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^blog25\.daleallen\.net$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/blog25/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
            <rule platformId="wdpVpr" name="www.bananapages.net virtual path rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^.*$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.bananapages\.net$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/bp/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
            <rule platformId="wdpVpr" name="bananapages.net virtual path rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^.*$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^bananapages\.net$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/bp/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
            <rule platformId="wdpVpr" name="blog.daleallen.net virtual path rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^.*$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^blog\.daleallen\.net$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/blog/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
        <outboundRules>
            <rule name="blog25.daleallen.net virtual path rewrite">
                <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_LOCATION" pattern="^(https?\://blog25\.daleallen\.net)/blog25/(.+/)$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{RESPONSE_STATUS}" pattern="^301$" ignoreCase="false" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}/{R:2}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="www.bananapages.net virtual path rewrite">
                <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_LOCATION" pattern="^(https?\://www\.bananapages\.net)/bp/(.+/)$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{RESPONSE_STATUS}" pattern="^301$" ignoreCase="false" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}/{R:2}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="bananapages.net virtual path rewrite">
                <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_LOCATION" pattern="^(https?\://bananapages\.net)/bp/(.+/)$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{RESPONSE_STATUS}" pattern="^301$" ignoreCase="false" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}/{R:2}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="blog.daleallen.net virtual path rewrite">
                <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_LOCATION" pattern="^(https?\://blog\.daleallen\.net)/blog/(.+/)$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{RESPONSE_STATUS}" pattern="^301$" ignoreCase="false" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}/{R:2}" />
            </rule>
        </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This seems like a configuration issue, and from the question, I'm not sure how much you understand about what web.config is. Have you tried changing things to fix your issue m

Comment: Yes, I have changed the web.config file several times trying different things but I can't get it to stop appending the physical folder name to the end of the alias (Redirected) URL.  Instead of getting http://blog25.daleallen.net I am getting: http://blog25.daleallen.net/blog25  the BLOG25 is appending to the end of the redirected URL.  Can anyone show me what is causing this to happen?

Dale